# Не устанавливается Docker на Windows

Tags: windows, docker

После открытия файла  `Docker Desktop Installer.exe` выдаёт Installation Failed.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Вот текст ошибки:*

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
> в CommunityInstaller.UninstallWorkflow.d__16.MoveNext()
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
> в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> в CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__27.MoveNext()
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
> в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> в CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__29.MoveNext()
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
> в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> в CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__28.MoveNext()
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
> в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> в CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__23.MoveNext()

Помогите пожалуйста, как решить мою проблему, или как установить Docker на Windows 10Pro?

Изменено:

Перед тем, как появляется ошибка, вылазит такая модалка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Docker'а в системе нету.

Comment: Что за редакция windows?

Comment: Посмотрите на инструкцию тут https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/. Если не помогает то ищите проблемы в самой windows.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня была такая ошибка из-за того, что предыдущая версия докера не удалилась полностью и отображалась в списке установленных приложений.

Помогла установка [Soft Organizer](https://www.chemtable.com/ru/soft-organizer.htm) и принудительное удаление через него. После этого новая версия установилась без каких-либо проблем.