# Ошибка при переустановке Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, windows-10

Потребовалось переустановить докер. Удаление было произведено по этой инструкции: https://qna.habr.com/q/664358, файлы в реестре почищены. Ранее при таком же удалении все нормально переустанавливалось.
Теперь не получается установить, так как якобы он уже установлен. При запуске установщика вылезает сообщение

> Do you want to replace your current version of Docker Desktop 2.5.2
> (50165) with this new one 2.5.3 (50261)?

Нажимаю "Да" - Installation failed со следующей ошибкой (вероятно, потому что нечего заменять):

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.    в
> CommunityInstaller.UninstallWorkflow.d__16.MoveNext()
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    в
> CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__27.MoveNext()
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    в
> CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__29.MoveNext()
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    в
> CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__28.MoveNext()
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    в
> CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__23.MoveNext()

В чем может быть проблема? Из файлов докера на компьютере только установщик сейчас.

Comment: на офф репозитории есть тикет с похожей ошибкой, но решений пока нет https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9459

Comment: ну и ранее тут подобный вопрос задавали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211371/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-docker-%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка оказалась в том, что предыдущая версия докера почему-то до сих пор присутствовала в списке установленных приложений. Обычным способом программа не удалялась (висело окно с надписью "Uninstalling..." и ничего не происходило).

Помогла установка [Soft Organizer](https://www.chemtable.com/ru/soft-organizer.htm) и [принудительное удаление](https://lumpics.ru/how-remove-remote-application-in-windows-10/) через него. После докер нормально установился.